# How to ensure user is authenticated before he publishes an article in Laravel in the below scenario?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-5

I am developing a simple web blogging application in Laravel 5.1. The application contains two controllers, a `UsersController` and an `ArticlesController`.

The `authenticate()` and `check()` functions that validate whether the user is authorized to carry out the operation are in the `UsersController`, and the `store()`, `update()` etc. features related to articles are in the `ArticlesController`.

How am I supposed to call the `authenticate()` or `check()` function from `ArticlesController` before say, `store()`ing an article to the database?

Comment: are u aware of request authorize() method ,maybe you should use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses middleware, in your controller you need to put this

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth'); //Requires auth

}
```

and in your routes you need to add the code for use middleware in your needed controllers like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Read the documentation of Laravel about Middleware you can create more middleware http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Answer (score 0):

You're question is not very clear, but I suppose that you want check if an user is authenticated before storing an article. There are many ways to do it:

1. Set a [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware) in the routing rules of your `ArticleController`.
2. Check the authentication in the `store` method using the "standard" `Auth` class.

Example:

```
function store()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        // The user is logged in...
    }
}
```